# ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Tags: python

I have the following two files:

```
/quiz/quiz/views.py
```

and

```
/quiz/static/questions.html
```

I would like to import `questions.html` into `views.py`.

So I'm trying to do this:

`from ..static import *`

However, I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Comment: you can't import html files into python

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the html file ?

Answer (score 1):

As Sebastian Wozny answered, you can not import such files in python.

Try to write module that parse useful data from html file then import that module.